# Using JMeter Docker image, Prometheus throws ConversionException

Tags: docker, jmeter, gitlab-ci, prometheus, jmeter-plugins

If I get the following error, is it because the Docker image does not have the plugin, and would the solution be to me to create an image containing that plugin?

Or can I use the Gitlab CI file to copy the plugin JAR into lib/ext on the image?

I am using the image `justb4/jmeter:latest`.

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/builds/guyl/web-performance-testing/./DCS_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_DTM.jmx'. 
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.github.johrstrom.config.PrometheusMetricsConfig
 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:66)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/com.github.johrstrom.config.PrometheusMetricsConfig
line number         : 132
version             : 5.4.3
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, looking at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/Dockerfile) the image contains vanilla JMeter only without any plugins.

I think you need to add a custom [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) directive which will:

- Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
- Install [Prometheus Listener Plugin](https://github.com/johrstrom/jmeter-prometheus-plugin)

Example code to be added to the Dockerfile :

```
RUN curl -L --silent https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ > ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar \
    && curl -L --silent https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar >${JMETER_HOME}/lib/cmdrunner-2.2.jar \
    && java -cp ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller \
    && ${JMETER_BIN}/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jmeter-prometheus
```